# How to write a query in KQL for Internal and External ip addresses

Tags: kql, kql-query

How do you write a query in KQL looking for external ip addresses and internal ip addresses

Answer (score 1):

The question is too general, so the answer will be very general too.

The following two links will help you with what you need:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ipv4-lookup-plugin
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ipv4-is-privatefunction